# How to create url mapping in web.xml

Tags: java, jsf-2, servlet-filters, web.xml

i want to create url pattern that lead to filter in jsf2.
I tried this code

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>www.mysite.com</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

but i don't get to my filter.
can you help?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting to map the URL path, i.e. the part of URL that follows host and your web application name.

This is how full URL looks like:

http://www.mysite.com:8080/myapp/path1/path2/path3

where:
8080 is a port - optional - default 80
myapp - the context path of your web application. It is empty if your application is default web application on your app server.

`path1/path2/path2`  the path. This is what you are mapping using `<filter-mapping>` tag.

So, if for example you want to pass through your filter all requests to JSP pages say:

`<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>`

If your UI is under directory `ui` and you want to filter such requests say:

`<url-pattern>/ui/*</url-pattern>`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get this right:

You want to point an URL to your already created *ServletFilter* in your JSF 2.0 web application?

You have to register your filter in your webapps *web.xml* file and map it to your desired URL, e.g.

```
<!--    register your filter -->
<filter>
  <filter-name>YourFilterName</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.your.filter.class</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>YourFilterName</filter-name>
<!--    Mapped to any URL -->
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: i registered my filter, i don't want all pages.